# Не прибавляется 1 час к DateTime

Tags: php

Пытаюсь прибавить 1 час к DateTime

Моя попытка:

```
$dateTimePayment = $objXfortaPayment->getStatusTime();
$maxDateTimePayment = $dateTimePayment->add(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 hour'));
```

Мой геттер(возвращает объект DateTime):

```
/**
 * @return DateTime
 */
public function getStatusTime()
{
    return $this->statusTime;
}
```

Comment: "Но не получается",..."Попытки безуспешны" --- не является нормальным описанием проблемы

Comment: Код рабочий. Скорее всего есть ошибка где-либо, но т.к. у тебя выключены отображения ошибок - ты её просто не видишь

Comment: Прошёлся xдебагом, ошибок не выявил

Comment: И чётко видишь значение $dateTimePayment  и $maxDateTimePayment ?  Потому что вот  простой пример https://onlinephp.io/c/ac017   - работает..